# Spring JPA with Postgres ltree extension (~ '*.)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ltree

Not working while getting

```
Message = could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract

pathToSearch = "a.b"

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_class WHERE path ~ '*.:pathToSearch.*{1}'", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyClass> getAllChild(@Param("pathToSearch") String pathToSearch);
```

Working in Native SQL i.e
`SELECT * FROM my_class WHERE path ~ '*.a.b.*{1}';`

Comment: @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_class WHERE path ~ '*.?1.*{1}'", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyClass> getAllChild(@Param("pathToSearch") String pathToSearch);

Comment: tried above still getting same error (Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:)

Answer (score 1):

*Please post complete stack traces formatted as code in the future. 
Stack traces carry way more information then just the error message. 
That said, I think I can correctly guess what is going on here.*

It looks like you are trying to use `:pathToSearch` as a bind parameter. 
But you made it part of a string literal: '*.:pathToSearch.*{1}'` therefore no bind parameter replacement is happening.

What you have to do is to assemble the complete string `*.a.b.*{1}` from its parts `*.`, `:pathToSearch`, and `.*{1}`.

You can do this in the database by using the [concat operation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-concat-function/)

```
SELECT * FROM my_class WHERE path ~ '*.' || :pathToSearch || '.*{1}'
```

Or you do it on the java side using a [SpEL expression](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions):

```
SELECT * FROM my_class WHERE path ~ :#{'*.' + #pathToSearch + '.*{1}'}
```

Comment: Great ! Can you show how to use SpEL with full example in this case ?, I have some confusion actually.

Comment: Just put the query in the `value` of `@Query`. Just be aware that I typed that query without being able to check it. So it might (i.e. probably does) contain mistakes that need some debugging.

Comment: Can you update your question with that information and a full stack trace?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in comments. Ask questions in questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alternative as below:

Query will give you all the child node of a path:

```
select path from test where path <@ 'a.b.c' and path <> 'a.b.c';
```

**JPA:**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE path <@ CAST(:pathToSearch AS ltree) and path <> CAST(:pathToSearch AS ltree)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Test> getAllPath(@Param("pathToSearch") String pathToSearch);
```